# How can I create a report with a custom object and add to a campaign

Tags: reporting, object

Currently I am unable to add to campaign from a custom report because to which I believe is because of a custom object that is not originally designed by Salesforce.

If someone could advise on how I could allow the add to campaign button to the custom report that would be greatly appreciated.

The custom object keeps track of data entered and we are interested in a report form of that data adding them to a campaign.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your custom object report needs to be tied to ***contacts*** or ***leads*** to be able to add records as campaign members - https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=campaigns_reportwizard.htm&language=en_US.

Is your object linked to contacts, meaning, is there a contact lookup field on the object in question?